# Why should I target the address and not the actual variable name when swapping values of two variables using functions?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, swap, pass-by-value, function-declaration

I'm fairly new to C programming and I don't get why swapping values of two variables when using a function shouldn't be the same as the normal way without using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int*, int*); //Swap function declaration

int main()
{
   int x, y;

   printf("Enter the value of x and y\n");
   scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);

   printf("Before Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

   swap(&x, &y);

   printf("After Swapping\nx = %d\ny = %d\n", x, y);

   return 0;
}
//Swap function definition
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int t;

   t  = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = t;
}
```

Why shouldn't it just be:

```
t = b;
b = a;
a = t;
```

Comment: Because that just swaps the local pointers, not the data in the memory they point to.

Comment: @Barmar So what you're saying is that those swapped variables are only accessible within the function and not in the global scope?

Comment: That's true, but not the point. Swapping pointers doesn't swap the contents of the variables they point to.

Comment: Here's an analogy: Suppose you have a blue box in your left hand, and a red box in your right hand, and you want to swap their contents. Switching the hands they're in won't do that. The hands are like pointers.

Comment: Because with pointers, you always have to remember the distinction between *the pointer* versus *what it points to*.  `b = a` copies the pointers.  (But that's not what you want.) `*b = *a` copies the pointed-to value: that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

`b = a` copies the value of a to b.

`*b = *a` copies the value in the memory pointed to by a to the memory pointed to by b.

When a and b are `int *` they contain the memory address of an integer, a pointer. In this case `b = a` will simply make b point at the same memory as a. `*b` says to "dereference" b and use the value it is pointing at. So `*b = *a` says to copy the value that a is pointing at to the memory b is pointing at.

This is all necessary because you are working inside a function isolated from the rest of the code. That function wants to change the value of two variables outside its scope, so it must do that by manipulating their memory.

`int *a, int *b` is like having two buckets named a and b. `b = a` makes buckets a and b the same. `*b = *a` copies what's in bucket a to bucket b. `swap` wants to swap what's in x and y's buckets.

---

Had you passed by value like so...

```
swap(x, y);

void swap(int a, int b)
{
   int t;

   t = b;
   b = a;
   a = t;
}
```

The values of x and y would be *copied* to a and b. The values of a and b would be swapped to no effect on x and y.

Had you passed pointers, but not dereferenced, like so...

```
swap(&x, &y);

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int *t;

   t = b;
   b = a;
   a = t;
}
```

Now the memory address of x and y are *copied* to a and b. a points to the same memory as x, b points to the same memory as y. But `b = a` swaps these addresses between a and b to no effect on x and y.

```
swap(&x, &y);

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
   int t;

   t = *b;
   *b = *a;
   *a = t;
}
```

The memory address of x and y is still copied to a and b. a has the address of x, b has the address of y. `*b = *a` changes the value of the memory they point to, the same as y and x. It is effectively `y = x`. x and y see the change.

Comment: In "passed pointers but not deref" (2nd to last example),`int t;` --> `int *t;` [or something to allow `t = b;` to compile].

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int x )
{
    x = 20;
    
    printf( "Within f( int ) x = %d\n", x );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    
    printf( "Before call of f( int ) x = %d\n", x );
    
    f( x );
    
    printf( "After  call of f( int ) x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before call of f( int ) x = 10
Within f( int ) x = 20
After  call of f( int ) x = 10
```

As you can see the variable `x` declared in main was not changed by calling the function.

The variable `x` was passed to the function `f` by value. That is the function parameter `x` (another variable that has the function block scope) was initialized by the value of the variable `x` declared in main.

So the function changed its local variable (parameter) `x`. The variable `x` declared in main stays unchanged.

You can imagine the function definition and its call the following way

```
f( x );

//...

void f( /*int parameter_x*/ )
{
    int parameter_x = x;

    patameter_x = 20;
    
    printf( "Within f( int ) patameter_x = %d\n", patameter_x );
}
```

To change the variable `x` declared in main you have to pass it by reference.
In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int *px )
{
    *px = 20;
    
    printf( "Within f( int ) x = %d\n", *px );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int x = 10;
    
    printf( "Before call of f( int ) x = %d\n", x );
    
    f( &x );
    
    printf( "After  call of f( int ) x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Before call of f( int ) x = 10
Within f( int ) x = 20
After  call of f( int ) x = 20
```

Dereferencing the pointer `px`

```
    *px = 20;
```

the function gets a direct access to the pointed object that is to the object `x` declared in main.

So if you want to exchange values of two variables declared in main within a function like `swap` you need to pass the corresponding objects by reference to the function. Otherwise the function will deal with copies of values of the variables declared in main.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting from dupe this swap has minimal sense. Use macro:

```
#define SWAP(a,b,type) do{type c__c__c; c__c__c = (a); (a) = (b); (b) = c__c__c;}while(0)
```